# "Turbo-timer" for safely shutting down after powerout

Tags: ups, shutdown, unexpected-shutdown

We have clients that apparently routinely kill the power to our running windows 7 platform without performing a shutdown.
We have had a couple of (SSD) drive failures that we suspect are caused by this behaviour.

Assuming education is impossible, does an *internal* solution exist that detects the powerdown, and supplies enough energy via some supercaps to last while the device performs a hardware shutdown on the PC?
We are severely space-constrained, so the device must be *within* the hardware system.

Comment: The solution would be to fire the personnel who are intentionally damaging company property.

Comment: @Hyppy: These are customers using their own hardware that we have sold. We are supporting them, and wish to prevent having to deal with this issue if possible. They can't fire everyone who misunderstands the shutdown procedure - this is but one step in a long, complicated, dangerous routine for them, and this is *not* a critical step in their minds (it's just a PC!)

Comment: I wouldn't look for a technological solution to a people problem in this case.

Comment: I agree it is a system failure - but why not eliminate this particular problem if it happens?
Backup systems are never a good idea?
Why have auto-correct? Just force users to learn their language better!

Comment: btw. do they pull the plug, or just use the button?

Comment: @Fox: pop the circuit-breaker. A hard-kill!

Comment: Ok, i was going to suggest cutting the powerbutton wiring. But yeah, bypassing the circuit breaker won't do :D

Answer (score 3):

There are SuperMicro [servers](http://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/BBP.cfm), which have battery inside.

And there are SSDs with supercap, like Intel's [PLI](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/ssd-power-loss-imminent-technology-brief.html) technology.

Edit: After quick googling I found this [internal UPS](http://www.beam-tech.com/flex/Internal-UPS-SI-Series.html). It looks dated, but may very well still be in production.